# Exploration and SLAM

Tags: slam, navigation, exploration, hector-navigation, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I would do the navigation and exploration of an environment and in the meantime to make a map of the environment. I can already carry a map with a launch file called neato.launch but I am moving the LIDAR in the direction that I want. Now, I would like to make a navigation and exploration, so I installed hector_navigation and I following this link to create nav.launch file:
http://answers.ros.org/question/112576/how-can-i-run-hector-navigation-for-exploration/
Then I run these commands:

```
roscore
rosrun xv_11_laser_driver neato_laser_publisher _port:=/dev/ttyUSB0 _firmware_version:=2
rosrun tf static_transform_publisher x y z yaw pitch roll frame_id child_frame_id period_in_ms
roslaunch hector_slam_launch neato.launch
```

because these are nodes of my neato.launch file, then I type

```
rosrun hector_costmap hector_costmap
rosrun hector_driving_aid_markers hector_driving_aid_markers_node
rosrun hector_elevation_mapping ElevationMappingNode
rosrun hector_elevation_visualization hector_elevation_visualization_node
rosrun hector_exploration_node exploration_planner_node
roslaunch nav.launch
rosrun hector_exploration_controller simple_exploration_controller
```

because they are nodes of nav.launch taken from link above. My questions are: is some command missing? How can I check from the map that everything is working properly? Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228430/exploration-and-slam/) by [papaclaudia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25634/papaclaudia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2016-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I really don't work with hector_slam yet, but for your question of checking the map you can use Rviz to visualize the current state of your `/map` topic

---

Originally posted by [jcardenasc93](https://answers.ros.org/users/21826/jcardenasc93/) with karma: 70 on 2016-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0